# Presheaves of $k$-morphisms associated to fibred $\infty$-category

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

In category theory one has presheaves of morphisms associated to fibred category as follows. Let $p : \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ be a fibred category. Let $U$ be an object of $\mathcal{C}$ and $x$, $y$ objects in $\mathcal{D}_U$. Then one has a presheaf of morphisms :
\begin{align*}
\underline{\text{Hom}}(x,y):(\mathcal{C} \downarrow U)^\text{op} & \longrightarrow \textbf{Set} \\
(V \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}U) & \longmapsto \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}_V}(f^\ast x,f^\ast y),
\end{align*}
given a cleavage of $f^\ast$. Is there a similarly construction for fibred $\infty$-category?

Comment: The usual way to translate such constructions is to first write the 1-categorical version purely in terms of fibrations – so instead of defining a presheaf of sets here, find a way to construct the corresponding discrete fibration. I admit this one is a bit complicated and I haven't worked out all the details yet, but it should be doable.